# Get all the div with a special content

Tags: jquery, html

So I have a html page of Facebook conversations. The problem is that all the conversations are mixed. So I'd like to have the conversations of a person I specify. The name of the person is in the div content. Here is what it looks like:

```
<div class="thread"> myName, ContactName
  <div class="message">...</div>
  <p>message</p>
  <div class="message">...</div>
  <p>message</p>
</div>
```

So for now I just did this:

```
<p id="test"></p>
<script>
var one = $(".thread").html();
$("#test").
$(".contents").hide();
</script>
```

My goal is to get all the div that contains the `ContactName` and display it in the `test` paragraph for example.
I want to know if there is a better way to get all the specific divs instead of using `if one[i].innerHTML.indexOf("word") //do something`. I would like to know how to directly access the html in a div, I put `<p>` in my example but I think a div would be more appropriate.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're trying to search for text, then .indexOf, or .test, are the way to go

Comment: Do you want to automatically filter the message? or you want something like placing a textbox and a button and then filling out the username in the textbox and hitting the button to filter out the messages?

Comment: No i just put my script directly in my page, nobutton. I'll try tomorow with indexof then. But if someone has a better idea.

Comment: Did you find any errors in console ?

Comment: Do you many users `div` of having class as `thread` ? You can use `.filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css selector `:contains` and get this done easily. [Working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/5m2v09av/)

```js
$(function() {
  var filterByName = "Raj"; //filter by this name
  var filteredDivs = $('.thread:contains("'+ filterByName +'")');
  $('#output').append(filteredDivs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thread"> Raj, ContactName
  <div class="message">...</div>
  <p>message</p>
  <div class="message">...</div>
  <p>message</p>
</div>
<div class="thread"> Max, ContactName
  <div class="message">...</div>
  <p>message</p>
  <div class="message">...</div>
  <p>message</p>
</div>
<div class="thread"> Raj, ContactName
  <div class="message">...</div>
  <p>message</p>
  <div class="message">...</div>
  <p>message</p>
</div>

<hr/>
<h2>
 Output of Filtered Divs
</h2>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

The output div now has the filtered div's. If you want the divs to stay on the main thread as well then you can go for cloning the elements and appending it.